# Go can't evaluate field when using range to build from template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have `Files` slice of `File` structure in my Go program to keep name and size of files. I created template, see below:

```
type File struct {
    FileName string
    FileSize int64
}
var Files []File
const tmpl = `
    {{range .Files}}
    file {{.}}
    {{end}}
    `
t := template.Must(template.New("html").Parse(tmplhtml))
    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, Files)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

Of course I got panic saying:

> can't evaluate field Files in type []main.File

Not sure how to correctly display file names and sizes using `range` in template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of your pipeline (the *dot*) is the value you pass to [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute) which in your case is `Files` which is of type `[]File`.

So during your template execution the *dot* `.` is `[]File`. This slice has no field or method named `Files` which is what `.Files` would refer to in your template.

What you should do is simply use `.` which refers to your slice:

```
const tmpl = `
    {{range .}}
    file {{.}}
    {{end}}
`
```

And that's all. Testing it:

```
var Files []File = []File{
    File{"data.txt", 123},
    File{"prog.txt", 5678},
}
t := template.Must(template.New("html").Parse(tmpl))
err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, Files)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JDorrjAMm7)):

```
file {data.txt 123}

file {prog.txt 5678}
```