# Go template: can't evaluate field X in type Y (X not part of Y but stuck in a {{range}} loop)

Tags: go, go-templates

[Similar question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124256/go-cant-evaluate-field-when-using-range-to-build-from-template), but I don't think it solves my problem.

Let's say you have the following struct:

```
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password []byte
    Email string
    ...
}
```

Moreover, the URL hasa structure like this: `example.com/en/users`, where `"en"` is a URL param that will be passed into the template like this:

```
renderer.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "users/index", map[string]interface{}{
  "lang":  chi.URLParam(r, "lang"),
  "users": users})
```

And in the HTML template I have the following:

```
{{ range .users }}
  <form action="/{{ .lang }}/users" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Username" value="{{ .Username }}">
    <input type="text" name="Email" value="{{ .Email }}">
  </form>
{{ end }}
```

Now, the problem is that because `{{ .lang }}` is not a part of the `User` struct then I get the error.. so how can I access `{{ .lang }}` inside `{{ range .users }}`?

Comment: You can declare vars in a Go template `{{$lang := .lang}}{{range .users}} ...`. https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The contents of dot (`.`) are assigned to `$` after invocation of `range`, so you can use `$` to access `lang` ([on play](https://play.golang.org/p/Nar7Pv5s9Z)):

```
{{ range .users }}
  <form action="/{{ $.lang }}/users" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Username" value="{{ .Username }}">
    <input type="text" name="Email" value="{{ .Email }}">
  </form>
{{ end }}
```

The behavior is documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables):

> When execution begins, `$` is set to the data argument passed to `Execute`, that is, to the starting value of dot.

If you are using nested ranges, you can always fall back to assign dot to something else using the `with` statement or variable assignment statements. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263399/1643939) for that.

Comment: Your syntax is off, and also it doesn't really work that way, the context is still set to the whatever you're ranging over. https://play.golang.org/p/Qz63RBwdZh

Comment: True. Fixing that.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a variable for `.lang`

```
{{ $lang := .lang }}
{{ range .users }}
  <form action="/{{ $lang }}/users" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Username" value="{{ .Username }}">
    <input type="text" name="Email" value="{{ .Email }}">
  </form>
{{ end }}
```

See here at the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can sadly just upvote since I accepted nemo's answer (since his was 1 minute faster and I ended up using it that way, although I'm sure in the future I'll want to do definitions like you showed, so wish I could accept both)