# Template can't evaluate field X in type Y

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

In Go I loop through a query result and append the results to a slice. I then try to display the data in html template, however I keep getting this error: `executing "orders.html" at <.Customer>: can't evaluate field Customer in type []main.Order`
Here's my code:

```
type Order struct {
    Order_id int
    Customer string
    Date_of_purchase string
}

func OrderPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
db := dbConnection()
var (
    order_id int
    customer string
    date_of_p string
    ps []Order
)
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer = 'David'")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(&order_id, &customer, &date_of_p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "there was an error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    ps = append(ps, Order{Order_id: order_id, Customer: customer, Date_of_purchase: date_of_p})
}
temp, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/orders.html")
if err != nil { 
  log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
}
err = temp.Execute(w, ps)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
}
```

My html template looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h3>Your username is {{ .Customer }}</h3>
{{ range . }}
<h2> {{ .Order_id }}</h2>
{{ end }}
```

I fetch the data from DB, just can't display it on html page.

Comment: Seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263280/go-template-cant-evaluate-field-x-in-type-y-x-not-part-of-y-but-stuck-in-a and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124256/go-cant-evaluate-field-when-using-range-to-build-from-template

Comment: I checked both those threads before and I still don't understand how to apply that to my code. I was following some online tutorial and all is nice and fancy save the template. Any idea what should I do in my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `ps`, a slice of `main.Order` to your template. In your template, `.` still is the slice.

Your line `<h3>Your username is {{ .Customer }}</h3>` tries to access the member `Customer` of this `[]main.Order` - which it doesn't have.

You probably want to get the customer name from the first element of the slice or pass a struct to your template that has this field, e.g. like this:

```
type Customer struct {
    Orders []Order
    Username string
}
```

Then you would need to change your template like this:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h3>Your username is {{ .Username }}</h3>
{{ range .Orders }}
<h2> {{ .Order_id }}</h2>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Let's say we forget about .Customer and I want to loop over orders inside ps only. How do I do that?

Comment: @davidb your template should work when you remove the `{ .Customer }` - the single dot references your slice. The range loop looks good, it should work as is

Comment: I get it now! I was planning on getting customer from somewhere else anyway so as long as this works I'm good to go. Thank you!